# Indexing arrays in CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Why doesn't CosmosDB index arrays by default? The default index path is

```
"path": "/*"
```

Doesn't that mean "index everything"? Not "index everything except arrays".

If I add my array field to the index with something like this:

```
"path": "/tags/[]/?"
```

It will work and start indexing that particular array field.

But my question is why doesn't "index everything" index everything?

EDIT: Here's a blog post that describes the behavior I'm seeing. http://www.devwithadam.com/2017/08/querying-for-items-in-array-in-cosmosdb.html Array_Contains queries are very slow, clearly not using the index. If you add the field in question to the index explicitly then the queries are fast (clearly they start using the index).

Comment: All properties are indexed by default, array properties included. Curious why you are suggesting they aren't. Do you have a particular query you're having trouble with? If so, please edit your question to clarify your specific issue. As written, this question is unclear, since we don't know your specific problem.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Arrays aren't indexed by default (though I agree they should be and all documentation indicates that they are, but they're not.) Without the explicit array index queries on the contents of the array take 10s of seconds and cost thousands of RUs. Add that index and the query returns instantly and costs a couple RUs. There's a blog post about it here: http://www.devwithadam.com/2017/08/querying-for-items-in-array-in-cosmosdb.html

Comment: Can you please clarify which API you’re using?

Comment: I use the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core package. And I also use the Cerebrata Cerulean tool.

Comment: Just did a quick test to make sure that the problem isn't with the particular library I'm using (or the tool I'm using which for all I know uses the same library). I wouldn't think so, I imagine these tools just pass the query on to Cosmos. But just in case I did a quick test using just the Azure portal and I see the same behavior.

Comment: this is no longer an issue with newly provisioned collections

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### "New" index layout

As stated in [Index Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-types)

> Azure Cosmos containers support a new index layout that no longer uses
> the Hash index kind. If you specify a Hash index kind on the indexing
> policy, the CRUD requests on the container will silently ignore the
> index kind and the response from the container only contains the Range
> index kind. All new Cosmos containers use the new index layout by
> default.

The below issue does **not** apply to the new index layout. There the default indexing policy works fine (and delivers the results in `36.55 RUs`). However pre-existing collections may still be using the old layout.

### "Old" index layout

I was able to reproduce the issue with `ARRAY_CONTAINS` that you are asking about.

Setting up a CosmosDB collection with 100,000 posts from the SO data dump (e.g. this question would be represented as below)

```js
{
    "id": "50614926",
    "title": "Indexing arrays in CosmosDB",
     /*Other irrelevant properties omitted */
    "tags": [
        "azure",
        "azure-cosmosdb"
    ]
}
```

And then performing the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM t IN c.tags
WHERE t = 'sql-server'
```

The query took over 2,000 RUs with default indexing policy and 93 with the following addition (as shown in your linked article)

```
{
    "path": "/tags/[]/?",
    "indexes": [
        {
            "kind": "Hash",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": -1
        }
    ]
}
```

However what you are seeing here is **not** that the array values aren't being indexed by default. It is just that the default range index is not useful for your query.

The range index uses keys based on partial forward paths. So will contain paths such as the following.

- `tags/0/azure`
- `tags/0/c#`
- `tags/0/oracle`
- `tags/0/sql-server`
- `tags/1/azure-cosmosdb`
- `tags/1/c#`
- `tags/1/sql-server`

With this index structure it starts at `tags/0/sql-server` and then reads all of the remaining `tags/0/` entries and the entirety of the entries for `tags/n/` where `n` is an integer greater than `0`. Each distinct document mapping to any of these needs to be retrieved and evaluated.

By contrast the hash index uses reverse paths ([more details - PDF](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol8/p1668-shukla.pdf))

StackOverflow theoretically allows a maximum of 5 tags per question to be added by the UI so in this case (ignoring the fact that a few questions have more tags through site admin activities) the reverse paths of interest are

- `sql-server/0/tags`
- `sql-server/1/tags`
- `sql-server/2/tags`
- `sql-server/3/tags`
- `sql-server/4/tags`

With the reverse path structure finding all paths with leaf nodes of value sql-server is straight forward.

In this specific use case as the arrays are bounded to a maximum of 5 possible values it is also possible to use the original range index efficiently by looking at just those specific paths.

The following query took 97 RUs with default indexing policy in my test collection.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM c
WHERE  'sql-server' IN (c.tags[0], c.tags[1], c.tags[2], c.tags[3], c.tags[4])
```

Answer (score -3):

Cosmos DB does indexes all the element of an Array. By, default, All Azure Cosmos DB data is indexed. Read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies

Comment: It doesn't though. Without the explicit array index queries on the contents of the array take 10s of seconds and cost thousands of RUs. Add that index and the query returns instantly and costs a couple RUs. There's a blog post about it here: http://www.devwithadam.com/2017/08/querying-for-items-in-array-in-cosmosdb.html

Comment: I read through that document again (I've read it many times) and it doesn't actually say that all data is indexed. It says that all documents are indexed. Not the same thing. So my question stands. Why doesn't "path": "/*" index all data when it seems like it should.