# What performance difference can I expect from the new index layout in CosmosDB?

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54540252/73226) the indexing layout has changed for newly created collections.

I have tested the case of [`ARRAY_CONTAINS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52725727/73226) queries and found very positive results compare with the previous range index behaviour.

What are the main differences between new and old index layouts and what scenarios are likely to experience significant performance differences (both positive and negative) that should be considered before migrating?

Answer (score 1):

I am from the Cosmos DB Engineering Team.

The new index layout is a collision-free, extensible, forward-looking index layout that addresses the shortcomings of the current layout, while setting up Cosmos DB for new query features including aggregates and GROUP BY (coming soon). IMO, dissecting the details of the new index layout is too much for a SO post, and it probably deserves a blog post of its own, which we plan to come up soon in the future.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know when the blog post is up!

Comment: Any news on this blog post?